# По работе сайта и настройкам сервера

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер, настройки

Есть один сайт, который работает на стареньком сервере и имеет вот такие настройки:

[image: Настройки / возможности]

Но сайт совершенно не хочет работать на другом, более новом сервере, вот с такими настройками:

[image: Настройки / возможности]

Подскажите, сайт не работает на новом сервере именно из-за настроек?

И если да, то могу ли я дополнить новый сервер настройками старого, чтобы сайт заработал на новом сервере?

Comment: я бы на Вашем месте дополнил вопрос хотя бы названием CMS, на которой работает сайт.

Comment: Что конкретно значит "не хочет работать"? Какие ошибки в логах хотя бы?

Comment: Он не на CMS. Он на статике HTML. Просто к нему прикручено оформление заказов, писанное на заказ очень давно. Оно представляет собой возможность закинуть на страницах сайта товары в корзину и оформить заказ. А для админа имеется админка, в которой видны заказы и можно ими управлять. В ней используется jquery-1.8.2 + PHP + MySQL. Не знаю, как точнее объяснить, так как не очень в этом понимаю.

Comment: Не хочет работать - имеется в виду, что при попытке оформить заказ, выдается просто пустая страница. При попытке войти в админку заказов - тоже пустая страница.

Comment: А вот эта картинка - с конфигурацией сервера - откуда берется? я задаю вопрос вот почему: конфиги сервера нужно, видимо, перенести на новый сервер. Вот я и пытаюсь понять, откуда можно взять эту информацию.

Comment: S.H., картинки с конфигурацией я заскринил с обоих серверов. 1-й - старый, на котором все работает. 2-й новый, на котором НЕ работает, но работают отлично новые сайты на движках и статике и на чем угодно. Да, я тоже думаю, что нужно просто НОВЫЙ сервер дополнить настройками СТАРОГО сервера. Это делается через ISPmanager? Просто на новом сервере в пункте Настройки/Возможности дополнить настройки такими, как на старом сервере? Или же это делается не так?